# Inserting to SQLite android not working

Tags: android, sqlite

When I add new Employee to department to my database it always returns cursor with only 1 entry and others are not added (here I am making trials on department with id 2)

> Activity code

```
 private EmployeesManagementDbHelper helper;     
 private  ListView employees;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.department);
    helper = new EmployeesManagementDbHelper(this);
    helper.addEmployee("Name","03-03-1990",2,"lk",null,null,null);
    helper.addEmployee("Name","03-03-1990",2,"lk",null,null,null);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    final long departmentId = intent.getExtras().getLong("departmentId");


    //setting list of employees in this department
    employees = findViewById(R.id.employees_list);
    Cursor cursorEmp = helper.getEmployessOfDepartment(departmentId);
    Log.i("depActivity",String.valueOf(cursorEmp.getCount()));
    //it always gets me 1 even if there are more

    EmployeeAdapter adapterEmp = new EmployeeAdapter(this, cursorEmp);
    employees.setAdapter(adapterEmp);
```

}

Method to insert new employee

> addEmployee

```
    public boolean addEmployee(String employee_name, String 
     employee_birthdate ,long department_id,String employee_job,String 
     employee_email,String employee_phone,String employee_photo){
    //adds an employee entry to employee table

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase(); 
    ContentValues cv  = new ContentValues(); 

    cv.put(EmployeeEntry.COLUMN_EMPLOYEE_NAME,employee_name);
    cv.put(EmployeeEntry.COLUMN_EMPLOYEE_BIRTHDATE,employee_birthdate);
    cv.put(EmployeeEntry.COLUMN_EMPLOYEE_DEPARTMENT_ID,department_id);
    cv.put(EmployeeEntry.COLUMN_EMPLOYEE_JOB,employee_job);

    if(employee_email!=null && !employee_email.isEmpty()&&!employee_email.trim().isEmpty()) // to be edited //checks if field is provided if not it is not added in the query
        cv.put(EmployeeEntry.COLUMN_EMPLOYEE_EMAIL,employee_email);
    if(employee_phone!=null && !employee_phone.isEmpty()&&!employee_phone.trim().isEmpty()) // to be edited
        cv.put(EmployeeEntry.COLUMN_EMPLOYEE_PHONE,employee_phone);
    if(employee_photo!=null && !employee_photo.isEmpty()&&!employee_photo.trim().isEmpty())
        cv.put(EmployeeEntry.COLUMN_EMPLOYEE_PHOTO,employee_photo);


    long flag = db.insert(EmployeeContract.TABLE_NAME,null,cv); 
    if(flag==-1) return false; 

    return true;

}
```

Method to get all employees working in a specific department

> getEmployeesOfDepartment

```
      public Cursor getEmployessOfDepartment(long department_id)
       {
    //gets all employees of a given department
    SQLiteDatabase db  = this.getReadableDatabase(); 
    String [] columns = {
            EmployeeEntry._ID,
            EmployeeEntry.COLUMN_EMPLOYEE_EMAIL,
            EmployeeEntry.COLUMN_EMPLOYEE_BIRTHDATE,
            EmployeeEntry.COLUMN_EMPLOYEE_PHONE,
            EmployeeEntry.COLUMN_EMPLOYEE_NAME,
            EmployeeEntry.COLUMN_EMPLOYEE_JOB,
            EmployeeEntry.COLUMN_EMPLOYEE_DEPARTMENT_ID,
            EmployeeEntry.COLUMN_EMPLOYEE_PHOTO
    };

    String selection = DepartmentEntry._ID + " =?"; //where statement
    String selectionArgs[] = { String.valueOf(department_id)  };
    String orderBy = EmployeeEntry.COLUMN_EMPLOYEE_NAME + " ASC";


    //cursor is a table containing the rows returned form the query
    Cursor cursor = db.query(EmployeeContract.TABLE_NAME,columns,selection,selectionArgs,null,null,orderBy); //don't forget to close the cursor after usage

     Log.i("helper",String.valueOf(cursor.getCount()));
    return  cursor; }
```

> 

```
public class EmployeesManagementDbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "employees_management.db";


private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;



public  EmployeesManagementDbHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

//This is called when the database is created for the first time
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // Create a String that contains the SQL statement to create the employee table
    String SQL_CREATE_EMPLOYEE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + EmployeeContract.TABLE_NAME + "("
            + EmployeeEntry._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
            + EmployeeEntry.COLUMN_EMPLOYEE_NAME + " VARCHAR(70) NOT NULL, "
            + EmployeeEntry.COLUMN_EMPLOYEE_BIRTHDATE + " DATE NOT NULL,"
            +EmployeeEntry.COLUMN_EMPLOYEE_DEPARTMENT_ID + " INTEGER NOT NULL,"
            + EmployeeEntry.COLUMN_EMPLOYEE_JOB + " VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,"
            + EmployeeEntry.COLUMN_EMPLOYEE_PHONE + " VARCHAR(20),"
            + EmployeeEntry.COLUMN_EMPLOYEE_EMAIL + " VARCHAR(255),"
            + EmployeeEntry.COLUMN_EMPLOYEE_PHOTO + " VARCHAR(255), "
            + "FOREIGN KEY(" + EmployeeEntry.COLUMN_EMPLOYEE_DEPARTMENT_ID + ") REFERENCES " + DepartmentContract.TABLE_NAME + "(" + DepartmentEntry._ID + ")"
            + ");";

    // Create a String that contains the SQL statement to create the department table
    String SQL_CREATE_DEPARTMENT_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + DepartmentContract.TABLE_NAME+"("
            +DepartmentEntry._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
            +DepartmentEntry.COLUMN_DEPARTMENT_NAME + " VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE, "
            +DepartmentEntry.COLUMN_DEPARTMENT_DESCRIPTION + "  VARCHAR(300) "
            +");";

    // Create a String that contains the SQL statement to create the task table
    String SQL_CREATE_TASK_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TaskContract.TABLE_NAME + "("
            +TaskEntry._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
            +TaskEntry.COLUMN_TASK_NAME + " VARCHAR(70) NOT NULL, "
            +TaskEntry.COLUMN_TASK_DESCRIPTION + " VARCHAR(300), "
            +TaskEntry.COLUMN_TASK_DEADLINE + " DATETIME ,"
            +TaskEntry.COLUMN_TASK_EVALUATION + "INTEGER NOT NULL"
            +");"
            ;
    // Create a String that contains the SQL statement to create the employee_task table
    String SQL_CREATE_EMPLOYEE_TASK_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + "employee_task " + "( "
            + EmployeeContract.TABLE_NAME+EmployeeEntry._ID + " INTEGER NOT NULL, "
            + TaskContract.TABLE_NAME+TaskEntry._ID+ " INTEGER NOT NULL, "
            + "FOREIGN KEY (" + EmployeeContract.TABLE_NAME+EmployeeEntry._ID + ") REFERENCES " + EmployeeContract.TABLE_NAME + "(" + EmployeeEntry._ID + "), "
            + "FOREIGN KEY (" + TaskContract.TABLE_NAME+TaskEntry._ID + ") REFERENCES " + TaskContract.TABLE_NAME +"(" + TaskEntry._ID + ") "
            +");"
            ;


    //executes SQL create statements
    db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_DEPARTMENT_TABLE);
    db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_EMPLOYEE_TABLE);
    db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_TASK_TABLE);
    db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_EMPLOYEE_TASK_TABLE);

}


//This is called when the database needs to be upgraded.
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // The database is still at version 1, so there's nothing to do be done here.
    // DATABASE_VERSION ++;
}

public Cursor getAllTasksCursor(){
    //gets all tasks
    SQLiteDatabase db  = this.getReadableDatabase(); //get readable instance of the db

    //specify the columns to be read
    String [] columns = {
            TaskEntry.COLUMN_TASK_NAME,
            TaskEntry.COLUMN_TASK_DESCRIPTION,
            TaskEntry.COLUMN_TASK_EVALUATION,
            TaskEntry.COLUMN_TASK_DEADLINE
    };

    //cursor is a table containing the rows returned form the query
    Cursor cursor =  db.query(TaskContract.TABLE_NAME,columns,null,null,null,null,null);

    return cursor; //don't forget to close the cursor after usage

}

public Cursor getSpecifiTaskCursor(long task_id){

    //gets specific task by its id
    SQLiteDatabase db  = this.getReadableDatabase(); //get readable instance of the db

    //specify the columns to be read
    String [] columns = {
            TaskEntry.COLUMN_TASK_NAME,
            TaskEntry.COLUMN_TASK_DESCRIPTION,
            TaskEntry.COLUMN_TASK_EVALUATION,
            TaskEntry.COLUMN_TASK_DEADLINE
    };

    //where statement to filter quere
    String selection = TaskEntry._ID + " =?"; //where TaskEntry._ID=task_id
    String selectionArgs[] = { String.valueOf(task_id)  };


    //cursor is a table containing the rows returned form the query
    Cursor cursor =  db.query(TaskContract.TABLE_NAME,columns,null,null,null,null,null);

    return cursor; //don't forget to close the cursor after usage

}

public Cursor getAllDepartments()
{
    //gets all departments
    SQLiteDatabase db  = this.getReadableDatabase(); //get readable instance of the db

    //specify the columns to be read
    String [] columns = {
            DepartmentEntry._ID,
            DepartmentEntry.COLUMN_DEPARTMENT_NAME,
            DepartmentEntry.COLUMN_DEPARTMENT_DESCRIPTION
    };

    String orderBy = DepartmentEntry.COLUMN_DEPARTMENT_NAME + " ASC "; //order by statement

    //cursor is a table containing the rows returned form the query
    Cursor cursor =  db.query(DepartmentContract.TABLE_NAME,columns,null,null,null,null,orderBy);

    return cursor; //don't forget to close the cursor after usage

}
public Cursor getDepartment(Long departmentId){
    SQLiteDatabase db  = this.getReadableDatabase(); //get readable instance of the db
    //specify the columns to be read
    String [] columns = {
            DepartmentEntry._ID,
            DepartmentEntry.COLUMN_DEPARTMENT_NAME,
            DepartmentEntry.COLUMN_DEPARTMENT_DESCRIPTION
    };
    String selection = DepartmentEntry._ID + " =?"; //where statement
    String selectionArgs[] = { String.valueOf(departmentId)  };

    return  db.query(DepartmentContract.TABLE_NAME,columns,selection,selectionArgs,null,null,null);

}

public Cursor getEmployessOfDepartment(long department_id)
{

    SQLiteDatabase db  = this.getReadableDatabase(); 

           String [] columns = {
            EmployeeEntry._ID,
            EmployeeEntry.COLUMN_EMPLOYEE_EMAIL,
            EmployeeEntry.COLUMN_EMPLOYEE_BIRTHDATE,
            EmployeeEntry.COLUMN_EMPLOYEE_PHONE,
            EmployeeEntry.COLUMN_EMPLOYEE_NAME,
            EmployeeEntry.COLUMN_EMPLOYEE_JOB,
            EmployeeEntry.COLUMN_EMPLOYEE_DEPARTMENT_ID,
            EmployeeEntry.COLUMN_EMPLOYEE_PHOTO
    };

    String selection = DepartmentEntry._ID + " =?"; //where statement
    String selectionArgs[] = { String.valueOf(department_id)  };
    String orderBy = EmployeeEntry.COLUMN_EMPLOYEE_NAME + " ASC";


    //cursor is a table containing the rows returned form the query
    Cursor cursor = db.query(EmployeeContract.TABLE_NAME,columns,selection,selectionArgs,null,null,orderBy); //don't forget to close the cursor after usage

    return  cursor; }

public boolean addDepartment(String department_name , String department_description)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase(); //gets writeable instance of database
    ContentValues cv  = new ContentValues(); //used for inserting an entry


    cv.put(TaskEntry.COLUMN_TASK_NAME,department_name);

    if(department_description!=null && !department_description.isEmpty()&&!department_description.trim().isEmpty()) // to be edited
        cv.put(TaskEntry.COLUMN_TASK_DESCRIPTION,department_description);

    long flag = db.insert(DepartmentContract.TABLE_NAME,null,cv); //reutrns a flag to indicate succes of insertion

    if(flag==-1) return false; //-1 if insert fails

    return true;
}




public boolean addEmployee(String employee_name, String employee_birthdate ,long department_id,String employee_job,String employee_email,String employee_phone,String employee_photo){
    //adds an employee entry to employee table

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase(); //gets writeable instance of database
    ContentValues cv  = new ContentValues(); //used for inserting an entry


    // no need to check for null as it is required to be provided
    cv.put(EmployeeEntry.COLUMN_EMPLOYEE_NAME,employee_name);
    cv.put(EmployeeEntry.COLUMN_EMPLOYEE_BIRTHDATE,employee_birthdate);
    cv.put(EmployeeEntry.COLUMN_EMPLOYEE_DEPARTMENT_ID,department_id);
    cv.put(EmployeeEntry.COLUMN_EMPLOYEE_JOB,employee_job);

    if(employee_email!=null && !employee_email.isEmpty()&&!employee_email.trim().isEmpty()) // to be edited //checks if field is provided if not it is not added in the query
        cv.put(EmployeeEntry.COLUMN_EMPLOYEE_EMAIL,employee_email);
    if(employee_phone!=null && !employee_phone.isEmpty()&&!employee_phone.trim().isEmpty()) // to be edited
        cv.put(EmployeeEntry.COLUMN_EMPLOYEE_PHONE,employee_phone);
    if(employee_photo!=null && !employee_photo.isEmpty()&&!employee_photo.trim().isEmpty())
        cv.put(EmployeeEntry.COLUMN_EMPLOYEE_PHOTO,employee_photo);


    long flag = db.insert(EmployeeContract.TABLE_NAME,null,cv); //reutrns a flag to indicate succes of insertion

    if(flag==-1) return false; //-1 if insert fails

    return true;

}

public boolean addTask(String task_name, int task_evaluation , String task_description, String task_deadline, ArrayList<Long> emplyee_ids)
{
    //adds task to db
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase(); //gets writeable instance of database
    ContentValues cv  = new ContentValues(); //used for inserting an entry

    cv.put(TaskEntry.COLUMN_TASK_NAME,task_name);
    cv.put(TaskEntry.COLUMN_TASK_EVALUATION, task_evaluation);

    if(task_description!=null && !task_description.isEmpty()&&!task_description.trim().isEmpty())
        cv.put(TaskEntry.COLUMN_TASK_DESCRIPTION,task_description);

    if(task_deadline!=null && !task_deadline.isEmpty()&&!task_deadline.trim().isEmpty())
        cv.put(TaskEntry.COLUMN_TASK_DEADLINE,task_deadline);

    long task_id = db.insert(TaskContract.TABLE_NAME,null,cv); //reutrns a flag to indicate succes of insertion

    if(task_id==-1) return false; //-1 if insert fails

    cv = new ContentValues();
    if (emplyee_ids!=null)
    {
        for(long emp_id:emplyee_ids){
            cv.put(EmployeeEntry._ID,emp_id);
            cv.put(TaskEntry._ID,task_id);
            long flag = db.insert("employee_task",null,cv); //reutrns a flag to indicate succes of insertion
            if(flag==-1) return false;
        }
    }
    else return false;
    return true;
}

public boolean deleteEmployee(long employee_id){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase(); //gets writeable instance of database
    db.delete("employee_task",EmployeeContract.TABLE_NAME+EmployeeEntry._ID+ "="+employee_id,null);
    int flag =  db.delete(EmployeeContract.TABLE_NAME,EmployeeEntry._ID + "=" + employee_id,null) ;
    return flag>0;


}

public boolean deleteTask(long task_id){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase(); //gets writeable instance of database
    db.delete("employee_task",TaskContract.TABLE_NAME+TaskEntry._ID+ "="+task_id,null);
    int flag = db.delete(TaskContract.TABLE_NAME,TaskEntry._ID + "=" + task_id,null);
    return flag>0;

}


public boolean deleteDepartment(long department_id){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase(); //gets writeable instance of database

    Cursor c = getEmployessOfDepartment(department_id);
    while(c.moveToNext()) {
        db.delete("employee_task",EmployeeContract.TABLE_NAME+EmployeeEntry._ID + "  = "+c.getString(0),null);
    }
    c.close();

    db.delete(EmployeeContract.TABLE_NAME,DepartmentEntry._ID + "=" + department_id,null);
    int flag = db.delete(DepartmentContract.TABLE_NAME,DepartmentEntry._ID + "=" + department_id,null) ;

    return flag>0;
}
```

}

Comment: Post your EmployeesManagementDbHelper class

Comment: I added it @mTak

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you shure about this line in `getEmployessOfDepartment`method:

```
String selection = DepartmentEntry._ID + " =?"; //where statement
```

As I know it will give you only a row with given _ID - so it will be always 1 row.
May be you should use `EmployeeEntry.COLUMN_EMPLOYEE_DEPARTMENT_ID` here, as I understand your goal it will be right.

Comment: Nice to help you. Ask if you have more questions.